# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework' in Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy a django application on AWS EC2 for the first time. I'm using Ubuntu server, but it happens that the packages I installed are not recognized, the packeges have already been added to the INSTALLED_APPS. The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

The error references any package that comes first in the INSTALLED APPS. In this case restframework comes first. If it is corshearder that comes first in the installed apps the error will be `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders` and so on. I know this behaviour occurs because the code is interpreted from top to bottom of settings.py file. I installed those packeges using `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`. When the issue kept occuring I rreinstalled the packages using `sudo pip3 install packge_name`. I activated the virtual enviroment before running the installations but none of the packages are found. I don't know for sure if I'm MISSING any steps because I know very little about linux commands. How do I install packages in my envirpment variable properly?

```
sudo pip3 freeze

asgiref==3.4.1
blinker==1.3
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
cloud-init==21.1
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==1.2.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2
django-cors-headers==3.7.0
django-countries==7.1
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-rest-resetpassword==0.1.2
djangorestframework==3.12.4
gunicorn==20.1.0
hibagent==1.0.1
idna==2.10
Jinja2==2.8
jsonpatch==1.10
jsonpointer==1.9
language-selector==0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
oauthlib==1.0.3
prettytable==0.7.2
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycurl==7.43.0
pygobject==3.20.0
PyJWT==1.3.0
pyserial==3.0.1
python-apt==1.1.0b1+ubuntu0.16.4.12
python-debian==0.1.27
python-systemd==231
pytz==2021.1
PyYAML==3.11
requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
ssh-import-id==5.5
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
ufw==0.35
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.26.6
```

Comment: Try to do pip freeze and see if the packages are installed ? So i don't very know EC2 well but do you need to create a env before deploy it ?

Comment: THANKS @Rvector. `pip freeze` didnt output any value but `sudo pip3 freeze` ouput packages but the packages I installed are not ammong. Please what should I do since I have run commands to install them as stated in the question but none of the installed packages are present in the output of `sudo pip3 freeze`

Comment: What did you got if you try `sudo pip3 freeze djangorestframework` ? Don't activate the env and install `requirements.txt` again

Comment: ```blinker==1.3
chardet==2.3.0
cloud-init==21.1
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==1.2.3
hibagent==1.0.1
idna==2.0
Jinja2==2.8
jsonpatch==1.10
jsonpointer==1.9
language-selector==0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
oauthlib==1.0.3
prettytable==0.7.2
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycurl==7.43.0
pygobject==3.20.0
PyJWT==1.3.0
pyserial==3.0.1
python-apt==1.1.0b1+ubuntu0.16.4.12
python-debian==0.1.27
python-systemd==231
PyYAML==3.11
requests==2.9.1
six==1.10.0
ssh-import-id==5.5
ufw==0.35
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.13.1
```

Comment: Now install the `requirements.txt` without activate any env. Just type `sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt`. And run your server.

Comment: That's the output I go when i ran `sudo pip3 freeze djangorestframework`. It is exactly the same out as that of `sudo pip3 freeze`

Comment: Yes it was a typo. Just `sudo pip3 freeze`

Comment: I deactivated the virtual enviroment and then run `sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt`. The packeges appeared when I ran `sudo pip3 freeze` at this point. But when I ran `sudo python3.6 manage.py migrate` (which is the command I ran that gave me the error I stated on the question) I'm still getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework' ` both with and without activationg the venv

Comment: Can you post a link to the `requirement.txt` file content plz. Or post the content here.

Comment: @Rvector. Pls check, I have updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurred because you have installed your dependencies using Sudo.
This has installed your pip dependencies only for Sudo users, whilst you are running your Django application as a non-sudo user. This is the reason why you didn't saw your packages when you did `pip freeze` but you saw them after doing `sudo pip3 freeze`

**To solve this**

1. Install `python3-venv` with this command `sudo apt-get install python3-venv`
2. Create a virtual environment `python3 -m venv env` this command will create a virtual environment named `env`
3. Activate the virtual environment with this command `source env/bin/activate`

Once you have done this you will see a `(env)` before your shell which indicates that your virtual environment is activated now need to install the dependencies inside this

1. `cd` to your requirements.txt and type `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` make sure you do it without sudo (because you will run your Django app in your web server as a non-sudo privilege user for security reasons)

After this, you can run your Django app with your virtual environment kept active.

Comment: I couldn't be more grateful for your insight in the mistake I was making. You're truly a Legend. Thanks so much

Comment: @Ruchit Micro Thanks, this was very subtle. Thanks a lot !